# Is there any way to get any of the other angels to fight with you?

Tags: the-guided-fate-paradox

There is an 'Angel Info' Screen and it seems way too empty with only Lilliel there for her to be the one and only party member option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right spot.  But you only unlock the other angels after you complete Chapter 5.

Once you do, in the Angel Info, you can select which angel you want to use, and up at the top, where it says, "Current partner" will change to the angel you just selected.  Since each has their own unique skill, this can be beneficial to your playstyle.

Comment: I just beat Chapter 5 and they were all unlocked at once. I was actually about to add it myself. I was afraid I was supposed to be talking to them the whole time.